# Java Spring Log4j Protected by Password

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I am using Java Spring 4.3.

I would like to ask if it is possible to secure the Log4J log with password?

I have received a requirement to secure the log file with password.

Comment: What do you mean by protecting a log file? Do you want to encrypt the content of the file while writing or what?

Comment: This question has been asked several times e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215944/secure-encrypt-log4j-files